# urllib2 isn't able to open a site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2, urllib

when I tried to open this link
(http://-travka-.tokobagus.com/)

urllib2 gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory>
```

I think there is problem with starting hyphen / dash.
How could I open such a url with urllib2?

Complete code

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'http://-travka-.tokobagus.com/'
#url = 'http://www.google.com'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
```

You see I use google.com instead and it's working fine.
May be it is a version-related bug?

mine are:

- Python - 2.7.4
- Ubuntu - 13.04

Comment: It's not BS that's giving you the error, but `urllib2`. Can you show your relevant code?

Comment: @aIKid code added. plz check

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What platform is this on?

Comment: Works fine here,  too.. Any other information we're missing?

Comment: @MartijnPieters   
could it be version problem ?
mine python 2.7.4 and bs4

Comment: I managed to get `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>` on one of Ubuntu's but can't yet get why.

Comment: @alko That's my result too on Python 2.6.8 /urllib2 2.6. I believe that's the normal error code for a failed DNS lookup. Maybe DNS is spotty for this subdomain?

Comment: @user3037901: This has **nothing** to do with BeautifulSoup. I tested with Python 2.7.5. I asked you about *platform*; your OS. Windows, Mac, Linux, something less often seen?

Comment: @MartijnPieters : ubuntu 13.04

Comment: @alko: It takes more than fixing the title; the misconception permeates the question.

Comment: did you guys get my question ?
then edit the title please.

Comment: sidenote: while urrlib2 and chrome successfully open resource on my win machine with different ISP from one with ubuntu, tracert and ping fail to locate web address.

Comment: That is not a valid URL.
RFC1035 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035 at the end of section 2.3.1 (And other documents too) indicate that the hyphen may only appear inside a name and not as the first or last character of a part of a name. I imagine that trying to look up an invalid name is likely to be troublesome!

Comment: @jcoder Useful comment, thanks! But chrome succesfully renders resource, and urllib at py 2.7.5 on win successfully opens it. So, as in general working with the url is potentially buggy, still reasons for the error in questions are not clear enough.

Comment: I wonder if it's confusing it with "punycode" / IDNA encoding for international domain names? They use hyphens to indicate the encoding...

Answer (score 0):

Will add this request for info as an answer, as it will be unreadable in comment. @user3037901, can you add traceback for following commands:

```
import httplib
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://-travka-.tokobagus.com/')
h = httplib.HTTPConnection(req.get_host())
h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, {})
```

Comment: I got an error **socket.error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

Comment: @user3037901 I meant full trace. at least three last lines

Comment: `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send`
      `self.connect()`
`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect`
      `self.timeout, self.source_address)`
`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection`
      `for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):`

Comment: @user3037901 this is c-extension error while address lookup. I wonder if our errors differ in sign due to ubuntu versions (mine is 12.x), so you're probably at dead end trying to access a bad named domain, that is with hyphen at the beginning.

Comment: @user3037901 if you don't mind, I'll transfer info from this discussion to your question and will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Here is the result:

```
Python 2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> stream = urllib2.urlopen("http://-travka-.tokobagus.com/")
>>> response = stream.read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
>>> soup.prettify()
u'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n <head>\n  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>\n  <title>\n   HERRY FIRDAUS NST | TOKOBAGUS.COM\n  </title>\n  <link href="http://-travka-.tokobagus.com" rel="canonical"/>\n  <meta content="-travka- telah menjadi member Tokobagus sejak 01-05-2013. Lihat profil -travka- selengkapnya di Tokobagus." name="description"/>\n  <meta content="index,follow" name="robots"/>\n  <link href="http://as.tokobagus.biz/v6/global/images/favicon-13.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico"/>\n  <link href="http://as.tokobagus.biz/v6/global/css/global.min.1.0.18.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>\n  <link href="http://as.tokobagus.biz/v6/skins/default/css/tbl.min.1.0.10.css" media="screen,print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>\n  <link href="http://as.tokobagus.biz/v6/skins/d
```